# What's the point of the WixMbaPrereqPackageId and WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl wix variables?

Tags: wix

What's the point of the WixMbaPrereqPackageId and WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl wix variables?

```
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx4Full" />
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="NetfxLicense.rtf" />
```

Are they only required if your bootstrapper application is of type `ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost`?

I've only seen examples with them having "NetFx" values:

- is that always the case?
- Does that imply that my custom bootstrapper library would always need the .NET framework as a pre-requisite?
- In that case can't I just have a `PackageGroup` with a `ExePackage` for the .NET framework installer?

If there is official documentation about these two variables, where is it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes the variables are only relevant for Managed Bootstrapper Applications.
2. I believe you can reference other package groups and include any packages as MBA prerequisites but I've never tried it.
3. No, only managed bootstrappers require the .Net framework. You can implement a native bootstrapper application (C++/COM).
   http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/ba/
4. Remember that there is a difference between prerequisites of the installed application and prerequisites of the bootstrapper itself. For example, If your bootstrapper gathers and validates database connection info, then that database's API package will need to be installed before your bootstrapper is executed.
5. Not that I know of. But WiX is open source, you can check for your self.